# How to pass received (bearer) access token to generated REST Client in order to invoke secured API-Gateway Endpoint

Tags: python, rest, swagger, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Im fairly new to AWS and its Cognito and API-Gateway services.
I have created in AWS a Cognito-specific User Pool and an AWS-specific API-Gateway API with some API-Endpoints to be accessed via REST API calls. The API-Gateway "Authorizer" is set to "Cognito".
After that, I have exported the Swagger document/OpenAPI2.0 using the AWS-Console specific export function and generated with the Swagger Editor a Python REST Client API.

The generated REST Client SDK generated the Model-specific "GET" function, e. g.:

```
# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.DefaultApi()
user_id = 'user_id_example' # str | 

try:
    api_response = api_instance.user_get(user_id)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling DefaultApi->user_get: %s\n" % e)
```

In order to get a correct result from the function call `api_instance.user_get(user_id)`
I need somehow pass the access token to that function.

The question is now, how do I pass the access token - which I have successfully obtained after the User signed-in - to the Python REST Client API in order to invoke an API-Endpoint function which has an "Cognito" authorizer set?

I saw many expamples how to realize this with Postman or CURL, but this is not what I'm looking for. I want to invoke my "Cognito" protected API-Endpoint in AWS API-Gateway with the generated REST API Client. I assume, there must be a way to put the received access token to the "Authorization" Header in the HTTP-Request call, before the generated REST Client function is invoked.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#cognito-requirements) a better alternative option for your execution flow?

Comment: @amitd: Thanks for your input. But it doesn't matcht to my question. The point is to make use of the API-GW SDK generated by the AWS Console. There must be a trivial way to pass the access token to the generated functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood you correctly, but this might help you.

```py
import requests
endpoint = ".../api/ip"
data = {"ip": "1.1.2.3"}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer MyBearerAuthTokenHere"}

print(requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers).json())
```

#Edit
You don't need to parse the response as json if it isn't. This is just an Sample.

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope, it is a bit more understandable now.